# Android + Room + attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: - After adding migration

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have added the Romm database library for one of my android application and using it properly for sometime now but now I have to update the app and I want to add the database migration to it.

I have followed multiple tutorials and blogs and official documents for that and tried add migration.

However, when I tried to add the DB migration, I am getting the same error even after adding the migration for multiple versions like,
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: (database path)`

Here is the code for the migration.

```
val MIGRATION_4_5: Migration = object : Migration(4, 5) {
        override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
//                database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE timetracker ADD COLUMN tempId TEXT")

            // 1. Create new table
            database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE timetrackerTemp ( 
            contentId INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
            time INTEGER, tempId TEXT );")

            // 2. Copy the data
            database.execSQL("INSERT INTO timetrackerTemp ( 
            contentId, time, tempId ) SELECT contentId, time, 
            tempId FROM timetracker")

            // 3. Remove the old table
            database.execSQL("DROP TABLE timetracker")

            // 4. Change the table name to the correct one
            database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE timetrackerTemp RENAME TO timetracker")
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for getting the database object,

```
daoInstance = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase::class.java, "myapp.db")
            .allowMainThreadQueries()
            .addMigrations(AppDatabase.MIGRATION_4_5)
            .build()
```

If anyone has any idea please help.

CRASH LOGS,

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.dev/com.example.content.appview.content.ContentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.example.dev/databases/test.db
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:3746)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3712)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3686)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1485)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.example.dev/databases/test.db
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1660)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1606)
>           at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.execSQL(FrameworkSQLiteDatabase.java:242)
>           at com.example.base.database.AppDatabase$Companion$MIGRATION_4_5$1.migrate(AppDatabase.kt:40)
>           at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:85)
>           at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.onUpgrade(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:133)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:256)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
>           at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:96)
>           at android.arch.persistence.db.framework.FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(FrameworkSQLiteOpenHelper.java:54)
>           at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:233)
>           at com.example.base.database.daos.TimeTrackerContentDao_Impl.getAll(TimeTrackerContentDao_Impl.java:134)
>           at com.example.content.appview.content.ContentActivity.onPause(ContentActivity.kt:600)
>           at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:6812)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1344)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:3735)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3712) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3686) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1485) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just scroll logcat and find result of migration. It should contain "found" and "expected" and scheme that you're using and scheme that room expecting. Then just compare field types and change migration to expected scheme.

Comment: added my crash log,

Comment: Thanks I have solved this.

Comment: Problem was in different field types?

Comment: yes, exactly thats the problem for autoincrement fields.

Comment: Can you tell me what was the error that was making this happen

Comment: Also, If everything seems correct and the app is still crashing even after adding the migrations to database builder, it is good idea to double check the SQL query to make sure all the fields are correct. For me, all fields were correct but I missed a closing `)` in the query which led to this error. The crash logs aren't always helpful for these kind of missing stuffs.

Comment: @HardikChauhan Hey hardik i am facing the same error can you please tell me what you did to solve this issue

Comment: I had issue in the autoincrement flelds i was declaring. there was a typo the name of the property was different than the original in db and the one i was declaring.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure the database schema has been changed to 5 as well

```
@[Database(
        entities = [
             /* ... */
        ],
        version = 5
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You must try 2 things for a solution:

- *Table name* and *column name* should be written as`` `table_name`,`column_name` ``;
- When using the operator **NOT NULL** should write **DEFAULT value**

  Ex.
  `` ALTER TABLE `card` ADD COLUMN `status` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ``